# working with FirestoreDocument

Tags: firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with FirestoreDocument and I am trying to retrieving document data.I am getting the post undefined.Below is my code for service and Component

**PostService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore,AngularFirestoreCollection,AngularFirestoreDocument} from 'angularfire2/firestore'
import {Post} from './post';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class PostService {

  postsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>
  postDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Post>

  constructor(private afs:AngularFirestore) { 
    this.postsCollection = this.afs.collection('posts',ref => ref.orderBy('published','desc'));
  }

  getPosts(){
    return this.postsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions=>{
      return actions.map(a=>{
        const data=a.payload.doc.data() as Post
        const id=a.payload.doc.id
        return {id, ...data}
      })
    })
  }

  getPostData(id: string){
    this.postDoc=this.afs.doc<Post>(`posts/${id}`)
    return this.postDoc.valueChanges()
  }

}
```

**PostDetailComponent.ts**

```
import { PostService } from './../post.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Post} from '../post';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-detail',
  templateUrl: './post-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-detail.component.css']
})
export class PostDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  post: Post

  constructor(
    private route:ActivatedRoute,
    private postService:PostService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPost();
    console.log(this);
  }

  getPost(){
    const id= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    return this.postService.getPostData(id).subscribe(data=>this.post=data)
  }

}
```

PostDetailComponent from console

```
PostDetailComponent {route: ActivatedRoute, postService: PostService}
post:undefined
postService:PostService {afs: AngularFirestore, postsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection, postDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument}
route:ActivatedRoute {url: BehaviorSubject, params: BehaviorSubject, queryParams: BehaviorSubject, fragment: BehaviorSubject, data: BehaviorSubject, …}
__proto__:Object
```

My post from PostDetailComponent is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of your code looks right, I think it's just that your `console.log(this)` is in the wrong spot.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getPost();     <----- your getPost() function is asynchronous
  console.log(this);  <----- meaning this console.log runs before you get data from Firebase
                             so when this runs, posts is still undefined.
                             If you would console.log(this) *AFTER* you get data
                             from Firebase, then you should see the values OK.
}

getPost(){
  const id= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
  return this.postService.getPostData(id).subscribe(data=>this.post=data)
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                        ASYNC portion is right here
}
```

To fix it, move your console.log inside your subscription:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getPost();
                    <--- From here
}

getPost(){
  const id= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
  return this.postService.getPostData(id).subscribe(data=> {
    this.post=data;
    console.log(this);          <--- To here
  });
}
```

**EDIT** - Additional troubleshooting ref comments below.

```
getPost(){
  const id= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
  console.log('id from route params is: ' + id);   <---- log the *id* too
  return this.postService.getPostData(id).subscribe(data=> {
    this.post=data;
    console.log(data);   <--- log *data* instead
  });
}
```

Comment: That didn't work.Still the post is undefined.thanks.

Comment: @jack I've edited my post to include some extra troubleshooting steps, can you include those console.logs and let me know the result?

Comment: id from route params is: Gh4WsAxIFxjfqfVj4WzR

data is undefined

Comment: @jack So that means you aren't even getting the data from Firestore. [Looking at the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes) I'm thinking there is an issue with the way you are querying your document... try using this syntax instead and see if you get a result from Firebase `db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot({
        // Listen for document metadata changes
        includeMetadataChanges: true
    }, function(doc) {
        // ...
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Since angular 6 there were changes on rxjs 
// replace `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`
with `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`
Then include `.pipe()` inside `PostService.ts` file in `getPosts()` function

like this:

```
    getPosts() {
     return this.postCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
      return actions.map( a => {
       const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post
       const id = a.payload.doc.id
       return { id, ...data }
      })
    })
   )
  }
```

Home someone helps, cheers !!!